# How to avoid overflow when counting anagrams?

Tags: algorithm, anagram

Let N be the size of a string. Let A, B, C..., Z be the amount of appearences each letter has in the string.

I need to calculate the number of anagrams: N!/(A!*B!*C!...*Z!).

The final result is assured to fit in an integer but the length of the original string can have any size.

The only idea I had so far was to prime factorize the numbers in the product, then eliminate the numerator factors that are also present in the denominator.

Is there a more practical way to achieve that?

Comment: How about using a bigint library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using 2 arrays with the terms of the multiplication for each part. Simplifying terms using GCD. Here is my C++ code: (Map has the characters and its respective frequencies).

```
unsigned int fatnk(int n, map<char, int> &k)
{
   vector<int> numerator, denominator;
   for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
     numerator.push_back(i);
   for (auto it : k)
      if (it.second > 1)
         for (int i = 2; i <= it.second; i++)
            denominator.push_back(i);
   for (int i = 0; i < numerator.size(); i++)
      for (int j = 0; numerator[i] > 1 && j < denominator.size(); j++)
      {
          if (denominator[j] == 1)
             continue;
          int d = gcd(numerator[i], denominator[j]);
          if (d == 1) 
             continue;
          numerator[i] /= d;
          denominator[j] /= d;
      }
  unsigned int ans = 1;
  for (auto it : numerator)
     ans *= it;
  return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the computation by interleaving multiplications and divisions, instead of doing all the numerator multiplications first and then dividing by all the divisors. Interleaving operations significantly reduces the size of intermediate values, but it doesn't quite guarantee that no intermediate result will be larger than the final result. With a little bit more effort, we can find an order of multiplications and divisions in which the divisions are always exact and no intermediate result exceeds the final result. (Skip to the sample code at the bottom of this answer if you don't care about an explanation.)

It's useful to understand why interleaving multiplications and divisions works. For the division to be precise, the intermediate value just before the division must be an exact multiple of the divisor. In this case, that's true because the multipliers are a steadily increasing sequence of integers.

Here's a simple example of the interleave, with just two letters. We want to compute (7 C 5), which is the number of anagrams of `aaaaabb`. (It's also a binomial coefficient because it's the same as asking the number of sets of 5 positions in a list of length 7. We can construct a unique anagram by putting `a`s in the five positions selected, and `b`s in the other two.) So the naive computation is:

```
  1   ×2   ×3   ×4   ×5   ×6   ×7   ÷1   ÷2   ÷3   ÷4   ÷5   ÷1   ÷2
  1    2    6   24  120  720 5040 5040 2520  840  210   42   42   21
```

The largest intermediate value there is 5040. That's not an overflow (unless we're using 8-bit arithmetic) but it's a lot bigger than necessary. Here's the interleaved option:

```
  1   ÷1   ×2   ÷2   ×3   ÷3   ×4   ÷4   ×5   ÷5   ×6   ÷1   ×7   ÷2
  1    1    2    1    3    1    4    1    5    1    6    6   42   21
```

Now, the largest intermediate result is 42, which wouldn't even overflow a `char`. We would get the same result if we divided by 2! first, instead of starting with 5!:

```
  1   ÷1   ×2   ÷2   ×3   ÷1   ×4   ÷2   ×5   ÷3   ×6   ÷4   ×7   ÷5
  1    1    2    1    3    3   12    6   30   10   60   15  105   21
```

With that order, there are more intermediate values which exceed the final result, but the largest one still doesn't come close to the original 5040.

It's evident that in both of the above cases, the division is exact, but it might not be so obvious why that must be the case. It's not that difficult to prove (using induction), but an intuitive explanation is not very complicated. Consider the (final) division by 5 in the second example above. In this simple case, there was no previous division by a dividend with factor 5 and there was certainly a previous multiplication by a multiple of 5, so it's unsurprising that the division is exact.

But suppose there had been a previous division by a multiple of 5. If so, that division must have been quite a long time earlier, because the previous four divisions were by numbers smaller than 5. In other words, at any point where we are dividing by `p`, the previous division by a multiple of `p` must be preceded by at least `p` multiplications of consecutive integers. And one of those multiplications must have been a multiple of `p`, since there is a multiple of `p` every `p` integers. Since there has not been a division by `p` since that multiplication, we can rely on that `p` still being part of the cumulative result, and so this division by `p` is safe.

It's also easy to see that the intermediate results following the divisions are monotonically increasing. That's because in a multiply/divide sequence, the multiplier must be bigger that the divisor; the multipliers are just an increasing sequence, while the divisors periodically reset to 1. And that in turn means that the largest intermediate value cannot be more than the largest divisor times the final result. So if we can do the intermediate computations in a slightly wider integer type, we'll be able to avoid overflow. That might be a good enough solution, but it's possible that the final result is allowed to be the language's largest integer type, in which case there is no wider type for intermediate computations. We need a better guarantee.

So let's return to the explanation of why when we are about to divide by `p` we know that the intermediate value is divisible by `p`. The key was that there must have been a multiplication by `p` within the most recent `p` multiplications. Now, consider the two possibilities:

1. The last multiplication was by a multiple of `p`.
2. The last multiplication was not by a multiple of `p`.

In case 2, the intermediate value before the last multiplication already has `p` as a factor, so we could do the division first. In case 1, the last multiplication itself is some multiple of `p`, so we could divide the multiplier by `p` before doing the multiplication.  And it's easy to know which of those two cases we're looking at, simply by doing a trial division of the multiplier by the divisor. With that modification, we guarantee that no intermediate result is larger than the final result, so overflow is not possible if the final result is representable.

Here's a simple C implementation. A variety of optimisations are possible, but I tried to keep it as simple as possible; since it's execution time is generally measured in microseconds:

```c
long long count_anagrams(int n, int letters[26]) {
  long long count = 1;
  for (int mult = 1, divisor = 1, letter = 0; mult <= n; ++mult, ++divisor) {
    while (divisor > letters[letter]) {
      ++letter;
      divisor = 1;
    }
    if (mult % divisor == 0)
      count *= mult / divisor;
    else {
      count /= divisor;
      count *= mult;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

A test case, verified against a simple Python program which uses bignums:

```
$ ./anagrams abcdddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeffffggg
There are 7467095163297369600 anagrams of abcdddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeffffggg
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to factorize numbers individually.  Just factorize the product of everything in the range 1..n.  That's a `O(n log(log(n)))` operation.  Then you can cancel things out.

Here is Python for that:

```
def factor_range(n):
    is_prime = [True for i in range(n+1)]
    factorization = {}
    
    for p in range(2, n+1):
        if is_prime[p]:
            power = p
            factors = 0
            while power <= n:
                s = power
                while s <= n:
                    factors = factors + 1
                    is_prime[s] = 0
                    s = s + power
                power = power * p
            factorization[p] = factors
    return factorization
```

(On my laptop this is able to give a completely factored version of 1000000! in under a second.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a map for prime factors of N, where keys are an int(prime factor), and value is count.
Do this map for N.

```
say, N = 10
factors = 2 x 5
map[2] = 1
map[5] = 1
```

Then traverse counts like A,B,...Z and find prime factors and decrease the counts from above map

```
say A= 5, factors= 5 x1
//just mark 
map[5] = 1-1 = 0

similarly, for B....Z
```

Now for the answer, start traversing map from largest prime factor, keep on multiplying key if value is positive and keep on dividing by key if value is negative.

```
    tmp = 5 , //largest prime factor
    result = 1
    for(int i=tmp;i>1;i--) {
      if(map[tmp]>0) {
        result = result * tmp * map[tmp];
       } else if( map[tmp]<0) {
          result = result / (tmp * map[tmp] * -1);`
       }
    }
    
    print(result)
```

Comment: Well, my question was exactly how to achieve the result without prime factoring